# Calling a class from another file in Cypress

Tags: javascript, class, cypress

I have a file helpers.js with those contents:

```
export default {
    green:'4bdd33',
    orange:'ff7900',
    red:'d92632',
  };
```

I want to convert it to a class  ,
I try to do that:

```
class colors {
        green='4bdd33'
        orange='ff7900'
        red='d92632'
      }
export default colors;
```

if that is the right way. in the body of the cypress test how can I import this the calss and using its properties.
I do that in the cypress test file :

```
import colors from '../../support/helpers';
```

and in the body of test i call its properties  in this way

```
 cy.get('selector').contains(colors.green)
```

but Cypress throw an error in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sebastiano's answer is the correct one. In this case, it doesn't make much sense to create a class to house constants. *But* if you did want to keep `colors` as a class, you'd simply have to instantiate it before calling it.

```js
const myColors = new colors()
cy.get('selector').contains(myColors.green)
// or...
cy.get('selector').contains(new colors().green)
```

As an aside, it is recommended that classes begin with an uppercase -- `Colors` instead of `colors`. When naming classes this way, you can have the class in uppercase and the variable instance in lowercase.

```js
export class Colors {...};

const colors = new Colors();
```

Comment: good complement

Comment: Thanks for useful explaintion.  it works .

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use a Class? Instead of using a Class you could simply export a JavaScript Object in your `helpers.js` file like:

```
export const colors = {
   green: '4bdd33',
   orange: 'ff7900',
   red: 'd92632'
};
```

And in your Cypress test file you can import **colors** with:

```
import { colors } from '../../support/helpers';
```

Then you can use **colors** as you already described in the question.

Comment: Yes it can be as your answer . Thanks